# StackNavigator title not showing in simplest example

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I just started React Native development, installed `Expo`, created an app (works), installed `react-navigation` and tried the first StackNavigator example using the example from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/.  I am running `npm run ios` from the commandline, and using `Nuclide` IDE. All of which are completely new to me.

The problem is, that on running the example the screen in the iOS emulator shows this:

[image: missing title bar]

Instead of showing a title bar with 'Welcome' on it.

As a beginner I have no clue where to go from here. Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rnproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.42.0",
    "jest-expo": "~1.0.1",
    "react-native-scripts": "0.0.30",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.44.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
}
```

there's an app.json file with these contents:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "17.0.0"
  }
}
```

I also added `flow`, which throws me no errors in the example code, but 115 errors in the `react-navigation` package. Most of them look like: `identifier 'expect', could not resolve name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found the answer [here](https://snack.expo.io/SksoGXR0l): To use the examples on `reactnavigation.org` in **Expo XDE**, you have to make some changes. Here are the changes necessary for the [first example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/#Introducing-Stack-Navigator):

```
import Expo from 'expo';  // <--- include this line
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,   // <- remove this line
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

// change the following line:
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
// into:
Expo.registerRootComponent(SimpleApp);
```